# Problem exporting RSA key -'key not valid for use in specified state'

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, encryption

I'm encrypting the web.config in our web sites using aspnet_regiis. However, I want the ability to export the encryption key so if we need to move from Machine A to Machine B, asp.net will be able to decrypt it.

When I run aspnetregiis -px "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" c:\keys.xml -pri, I get the following : 'Key not valid for use in specified state'. I've seen all kinds of responses online but they don't seem to apply. It's not an invalid key because when I use aspnet_regiis to encrypt sections of the web.config, they encrypt fine.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the key set as exportable on creation, say Machine A is the machine it is created on

Run this command on Machine A:

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" –exp
```

Then import the key on Machine B:

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "iListingKeys" "C:\New Folder\NetFrameworkConfigurationKey.xml"
```

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yxw286t2.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you trying export private key that marked as non-exportable.